# backend document combobox field value not shown on webpage

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes

I have simple combobox I bind to backend document. It has 10 years (starting previous year) in dropdown as values to select from with empty one, i.e. ["", "2018", "2019", "2020", "2021", "2022", "2023", "2024", "2025", "2026", "2027", "2028"]. It works fine. But if I change document in Notes Client and put value not from the list (e.g. 2030) then binding value not shown on webpage. How to add backend document value to the list of options?

```
<xp:comboBox value="#{document1.docYear}" id="docYear">
    <xp:selectItems>
        <xp:this.value>
            <![CDATA[#{javascript:var arr = new Array("");
                      var year = new Date().getFullYear();
                      year = year - 1;
                      arr.push(year.toString());

                      for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
                        var yearStr = year + i;
                        arr.push(yearStr.toString());
                      }

                      return arr;}]]>
        </xp:this.value>
    </xp:selectItems>
</xp:comboBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by adding:

```
arr.push(document1.getDocument().getItemValueString("yearField"));

return @Unique(arr);
```